# Remove section numbering from specific sections in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I want to remove the number only from the first two sections, i.e. Acknowledgement and abstract.  The rest of the sections should retain their numbering.

I also want the above two (acknowledgement and abstract) to appear in same format as 'Contents', same alignment and bold.

As a side note, I am not referring to page numbering, but section numbering. Just in case I was not clear enough.  Thanking you in advance for your support

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref} %to put live links to chapters
\usepackage{tocbibind} %add list of figures etc. in TOC


\author{The Author Name}
\title{Examining the effectiveness of teaching of....}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\clearpage


\section{Acknowledgements}
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
\section{Abstract}
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 

\section{Background of research}
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 

\chapter{Purpose of the study}

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
\section{Research Questions}
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should try with `\section*{Acknowledgements}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}` (and the same with `Abstract`).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\section*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}
```

Comment: Since the ToC is formatted as a `\chapter` under `report`, it's probably advisable to use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}`.

Comment: I used your recommendation, it worked.